# How to run firefox browser as a different user with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run Firefox as a different user in my Selenium tests. How can I tell Selenium to 'run as' a specified user? 
My application has a windows authentication, and I need to run tests with different roles.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by creating Firefox profile, use firefox.exe -p to launch profile manager

Once the profile is created as required use the profile name and launch the driver:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("profileName");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I my case solution was found: I was open Eclipse/command line as a different user, and execute test. This was selenium opens firefox window as a different user also.